# How to perform chi-square test for more than 2 variables?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I want to test with the chi-squared test if there is a difference between the number of stars of a hotel for each country and the gender of a booker.
An example of my dataset, `bookings`, is:

```
country     gender  numbofStars
Germany       male            0
Netherlands female            0
Belgium       male            5
Netherlands   male            3
Germany       male            3
Belgium     female            2
Germany     female            1
Netherlands   male            4
```

The number of stars can be variable between 0 and 5 stars. Do you have any suggestions to use the chi-squared test on the different groups?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having more than 2 levels in one of the variables you compare with a chi-squared test. See for example the first example in `?chisq.test` that compares gender (2 levels) to political affiliation (3 levels) [Agresti, 2007].

Comment: @VincentGuillemot It is not the multiple factors. Instead, there is a tiny "problem" with more than 3 factors. To do a chisquared test one would make a contingency matrix (with more than 3 dimensions) for counts in occurrences of 'country x gender x numbofstars'. This can not be done with chisq.text, and needs to be done manually.

Comment: This is a bit of an x-y problem ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )  the explicit question ask about more than 2 groups, but the underlying problem is much wider than this, and not only because of the more than 2 dimensions being a bigger problem for standard R functions, as pointed out in Peter's answer.

Comment: I suggest to change the title into 'how to perform a chi-squared test on tables with multiple dimensions'.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, the question is formulated in such a way that I assumed that a chi-squared test would be performed per country. If this is not the case, then the question needs to be reformulated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Chi-Square Test of Independence the best option for 3x2 contingency table?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398036/is-the-chi-square-test-of-independence-the-best-option-for-3x2-contingency-table)

Answer (score 6):

First, your issue is not about multiple *levels* but more than 2 *variables*.  It is possible to do chi-square on a 3 dimensional table, but I don't know how to do it in R. However:

Second: Why are you trying to use chi-square here? This seems like a regression problem. Number of stars is the dependent variable, gender and country are independent variables (and you may want their interaction, too).  Since stars can only be a non-negative integer, you may consider a count regression model (e.g. Poisson or negative binomial).

Comment: Chi-square is a correlation test so probably she wants to test whether there's any autocorrelation first before the regression tests.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would treat `numbofStars` as an ordinal variable.  It seems to me to be more akin to a Likert rating than an actual count.

Fortunately, R has the *ordinal* package, which allows for ordinal regression as flexible as standard OLS regression.

In addition to the analysis of deviance below, [Objects from this package are supported by the *emmeans* package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html), which you can use for post-hoc testing.

The [webpage listed in the example below](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_11.html) has a few other tricks, like getting a pseudo *r-square* for the model.

A couple of notes on the following example:

1) The dependent variable must be an ordered factor in R.

2) The *RVAideMemoire* package modifies *car::Anova* to handle the *clm* object correctly.  Be careful you don't use *car::Anova* without *RVAideMemoire* or you may get wildly incorrect results.  If you don't like this, you can use *anova* to compare models, or *emmeans* to set up contrasts.

```
### This example adopted from
### http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_11.html

if(!require(ordinal)){install.packages("ordinal")}
if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}
if(!require(RVAideMemoire)){install.packages("RVAideMemoire")}

Data = read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"country     gender  numbofStars
Germany       male            0
Netherlands female            0
Belgium       male            5
Netherlands   male            3
Germany       male            3
Belgium     female            2
Germany     female            1
Netherlands   male            4
")

Data$numbofStars = factor(Data$numbofStars, ordered=TRUE)

levels(Data$numbofStars)

   ### [1] "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

library(ordinal)

Model = clm(numbofStars ~ gender + country, data=Data)

library(car)

library(RVAideMemoire)

Anova(Model, type = "II")

   ### Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
   ###
   ### Response: numbofStars
   ###        LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
   ### gender    5.5818  1    0.01815 *
   ### country   4.3381  2    0.11429
```

Answer (score 2):

You could compute **manually** the expectated numbers for country, gender and score, $E_{ijk}$, based on the group totals (with independence as hypothesis):

$$E_{ijk} = T \frac{T_{i}}{T}*\frac{T_{j}}{T}*\frac{T_{k}}{T}$$

with T the total of individuals, $T_{i}$ the total number of individuals of country $i$, $T_{j}$ the total individuals of gender $j$, $T_{k}$ the total number of individuals of score $k$.

Then together with the observed numbers $O_{ijk}$ and the typical formula $$\chi^2 = \sum (O_{ijk}-E_{ijk})^2/E_{ijk}$$ you get a $\chi^2$ statistic for which you can calculate the cumulative probability `pchisq` by using $i j k -(i-1)-(j-1)-(k-1)-1 = ijk -i-j-k+2$ degrees of freedom.

---

Note that the R function `chisq.test` uses the check for small expectation values (when the normal approximation to the binomial distribution starts to deviate too much)

```
if (any(E < 5) && is.finite(PARAMETER)) 
    warning("Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect")
```

and this is not performed when you do these calculations manually.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific case, I like the suggestion in my other answer better.  But this one addresses the question asked:  How to do a test of association on a table of nominal counts with more than two dimensions.

~

There are a couple of relatively easy approaches to determine if there's an association on a contingency table with three dimensions.

The Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel test can be used for 3-dimensions only.  One dimension needs to be identified as the stratifying dimension, so it tests the independence of the variables of the m x n tables within k strata.  Some versions of the test allow for only 2 x 2 tables within the strata.  In your case it makes sense to test for the association of *gender* and *numbofStars*, and treat *country* as the stratifying variable.

Another approach is to use log-linear models, which test for association among nominal variables.  They can test for mutual independence,conditional independence, or partial independence. [The references listed here may be helpful in understanding these options](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_08.html).

See the links listed in the code for ideas for post-hoc testing and testing assumptions.

```
### These examples adopted from
### http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_06.html
### http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_08.html

if(!require(MASS)){install.packages("MASS")}
```

I'll need to simulate some data for these examples.

Note that in constructing the table, *country* is the stratifying variable, and is listed third in the *xtabs* function.

```
set.seed(12345)

gender = c(rep("Male", 36), rep("Female", 36))
country  = rep(c("Belgium", "Germany", "Netherlands"), 24)
numbofStars = c(sample(c(0:4), 36, replace=TRUE), sample(c(1:5), 36, replace=T))

Data = data.frame(country, gender, numbofStars)

Data$numbofStars = factor(Data$numbofStars)

levels(Data$numbofStars)

Table = xtabs( ~ gender + numbofStars + country,
              data=Data)

ftable(Table)
```

Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel test:

```
mantelhaen.test(Table)

### Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test
###
### data:  Table
### Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel M^2 = 19.765, df = 5, p-value = 0.001383
```

Log-linear model:

```
library(MASS)

loglm( ~ gender + numbofStars + country,
       Table)

### Call:
### loglm(formula = ~gender + numbofStars + country, data = Table)
###
### Statistics:
###                       X^2 df    P(> X^2)
### Likelihood Ratio 48.69355 27 0.006417156
### Pearson          40.27253 27 0.048305047
```

Comment: This test is interesting to note but it does not answer the (unclear) question. If you do a CMH test, treating *country* as a stratifying variable, then this means that you do *not* test for independence among/between countries, and instead only test the independence among gender and scores within the countries.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings ,Right.  Any thoughts on the log-linear model approach?

Comment: The loglm model seems very close to the concept of the $\chi^2$ test on tables. It models the observations based on a product of factors (or sum in the log formula). I do not know what the Likelihood ratio refers to, and also I wonder how this model makes an assessment of the error. I believe it makes an estimate of variance of errors based on the residuals, while the chi-square test, assuming count data, does this based on the predicted means. I guess that this makes the chi-square test slightly more precise and the loglm test slightly underestimating the error (because the variance of s).