Statistical test to show differences between two categorical datasets
I have two categorical datasets that I would like to compare against each other, but I'm not exactly sure which test to choose and how to go about it. Both datasets show the number of cases for 8 different environmental combinations in a 4x2 table. These two datasets have the same 8 different environmental combination, but the overarching is that dataset A is for "location A", and dataset B is in "location B"
dataset A:




A
B
C
D




E
732
150
183
76


F
202
149
129
38



dataset B:




A
B
C
D




E
348
369
408
195


F
333
238
349
164



The datasets look different from each other (combination AE in the top left box in dataset A is by far the most common combination and dataset B is more evenly distributed among the the conditions) and their percentages and thus proportions are different. I would like to like to employ a test to definitively show that they're different. Does anyone know the best one to use? I have seen McNemar's chi squared, Pearsons X^2 test, paired t-test, but i'm not too sure what is the best method is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

First you need to be very clear about what you want to prove; just that the 2 datasets are different? Second you may want to simplify your problem. You have here a 3-dimensional comparison. Datasets 1 and 2, accross 4 conditions (a-D), themselves accross 2 additional conditions (E, F). I would first try to simplify the problem some. E.g. Just have 8 conditions (EA, EB, ...FD); now you are down to a 2 dimensional comparisons, and there are many methods for this (Fisher, Chi square, etc.).  ...cont

...cont. If you have to be in 3-D, then look up this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332528/how-to-perform-chi-square-test-for-more-than-2-variables.
